# SqlCommand issues using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am troubleshooting a website in which data is loading from SQL Server but it breaks while executing `SqlCommand`.

SQL Server contains stored procedures, including one called `TollCollectionsReport`.

Here's my code:

```
SqlConnection con;
DataSet datSet = new DataSet();

string connString = "xyz";
con = new SqlConnection(connString);
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandTimeout = 360000;
cmd.CommandText = "TollCollectionsReport";

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ShiftID", Web.ShiftID));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ShiftStatus", Web.ShiftStatus));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IsShiftBased", rdoShiftTimeBase.SelectedValue));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ReportStartDate", startDate));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ReportEndDate", endDate));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@BoothCodes", BoothCodes));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SystemUserIDs", OperatorCodes));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CategoryCodes", CategoryCodes));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PaymentModes", PaymentModesCodes));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Hours", TimeIntervalCodes));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ReportCriteria", ddlReportCritera.SelectedItem.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IsSimpleBooth", rdbtnBoothIsSimple.SelectedValue));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IsSimpleOperator", rdbtnOperaotrIsSimple.SelectedValue));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IsSimpleShiftType", rdoShiftTypes.SelectedValue));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IsSimpleCategory", rdoCategories.SelectedValue));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IsSimplePaymentMode", rdoPaymentModes.SelectedValue));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IsSimpleHour", rdoTimeSequence.SelectedValue));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@GroupingSequence", groupingSequence));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@HourIntervals", Session["TimeInterval"].ToString()));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IsRangeSelected", isRangeSelected));

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Connection = con;
string tDate = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
adp.Fill(datSet);
```

Results:

[image]

While executing the code the values of Web.shift id are showing in first picture ... but when I call

```
string tDate = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

to get the query the results of `shiftID` is changed shown in below picture...

[image]

The arrow mark in picture shows that rest of values are not present...

And when I want to fill the datatable I get an exception because there is comma (`,`) at the end of `shiftID,`.

Please help me out so that I can get the complete query and fill the datatable... give me an example weather it is the problem of code or stored procedures used in the database. Guide me with example please please please...

Comment: What is the length of `@ShiftStatus` in your proc, looks like it is less than the value provided in the parameter, thus truncating the values.

Comment: looks like it is defined as `@ShiftStatus varchar(25)`

Comment: @Habib is right - make it varchar(MAX)